# Counting Records by Multiple Criteria and Including Different Service Types

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query that calculates the total number of records (`count`) for each combination of region, identifier, and service provider. The total count is obtained through a subquery that counts records in the `service_jobs` and `service_transactions` tables, considering specific conditions related to operator and service provider IDs. The final result is grouped by the mentioned fields.

```
select 
    region, meta_service_name, provider, 
    sum(count) as count
from
    (select 
         sp.provider_id as provider,
         ms.name        as meta_service_name,
         ms.region,
         (select count(*)
          from service_jobs sj
          join service_transactions st on st.purchase_id = sj.purchase_id
          where sj.type = 'SERVICE'
            and st.operator_id = sp.operator_id
            and st.provider = sp.provider_id) as count
     from 
         service_providers sp
     join 
         service_meta_services ms on ms.id = sp.meta_service_id) as first
group by 
    region, provider, meta_service_name;
```

I need to change the query to take into account the different types of services defined in the `service_transactions` table. There are four service types: `a_count`, `b_count`, `c_count`, and `d_count`. The service type is determined by the `A_Service`, `B_Service`, `C_Service`, and `D_Service` columns in the `service_transactions` table. For example, to include a service A in the count, the corresponding column (`A_*` for A, etc.) must not be null.

I tried using UNION ALL, but I believe there's a better solution that I can't seem to reach. With UNION ALL, the query becomes extensive.

```
select region, meta_service_name, provider, sum(count) as count
from (select sp.provider_id                       as provider,
             ms.name                               as meta_service_name,
             ms.region,
             (select count(*)
              from service_jobs sj
                       join service_transactions st on st.purchase_id = sj.purchase_id
              where sj.type = 'SERVICE'
                and st.operator_id = sp.operator_id
                and st.provider = sp.provider_id
                and sj.A_Service is not null) as count
      from service_providers sp
               join service_meta_services ms on ms.id = sp.meta_service_id) as first
group by region, provider, meta_service_name;

UNION ALL 

select region, meta_service_name, provider, sum(count) as count
from (select sp.provider_id                       as provider,
             ms.name                               as meta_service_name,
             ms.region,
             (select count(*)
              from service_jobs sj
                       join service_transactions st on st.purchase_id = sj.purchase_id
              where sj.type = 'SERVICE'
                and st.operator_id = sp.operator_id
                and st.provider = sp.provider_id
                and sj.B_Service is not null) as count
      from service_providers sp
               join service_meta_services ms on ms.id = sp.meta_service_id) as first
group by region, provider, meta_service_name;
....
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score -1):

To optimize your SQL query and include counts for different service types without relying on multiple UNION ALL statements, you can utilize conditional aggregation. This method involves using CASE statements within your aggregation function to count rows based on specific conditions.

This approach will allow you to calculate counts for each service type (A_Service, B_Service, C_Service, D_Service) in a single query, avoiding the complexity and performance overhead of multiple unions.

Here's how you can modify your query:

```
SELECT 
    region, 
    meta_service_name, 
    provider, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN sj.A_Service IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sj.B_Service IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sj.C_Service IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sj.D_Service IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d_count
FROM 
    service_providers sp
    JOIN service_meta_services ms ON ms.id = sp.meta_service_id
    JOIN service_jobs sj ON sj.provider_id = sp.provider_id
    JOIN service_transactions st ON st.purchase_id = sj.purchase_id
WHERE 
    sj.type = 'SERVICE'
    AND st.operator_id = sp.operator_id
    AND st.provider = sp.provider_id
GROUP BY 
    region, 
    provider, 
    meta_service_name;
```

In this query, we use SUM with a CASE statement to conditionally count records for each service type. The CASE statement checks if the corresponding service column is not null and then counts it if the condition is true.

This way, you'll get a sum for each service type (a_count, b_count, c_count, d_count) for each combination of region, provider, and meta_service_name, all in a single, more efficient query.

Comment: [Please refrain from using ChatGPT to generate your answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)